# TLS 1.2 library linking

Tags: c++, linux, ssl, openssl, tls1.2

Our application (C++) is using libssl.so and libcrypto.so on Linux RHEL 6 for TLS 1.0 connection. The “.a” file corresponding to both “.so” file gets linked to our application. I am looking for both libssl.so and libcrypto.so and corresponding “.a” file so that our application uses TLS 1.2

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking even though I believe I understand the topics involved.  Please describe exactly what you do, what you expect to happen and what happens instead.

Comment: Upgrade your OS to one that's somewhat up to date.